# django-pivot, ValueError: Column aliases cannot contain whitespace characters, quotation marks, semicolons, or SQL comments

Tags: python, django, pivot-table

I used django-pivot packages and I have got above error.

first it work correcly in jupyter:

[image]

but when I try to use companyid__company field instead of companyid field I've got this error
(Column aliases cannot contain whitespace characters, quotation marks, semicolons, or SQL comments.)

[image]
[image]

***Models:***

```
class TblCompany(models.Model):  
    companyid = models.AutoField(db_column='CompanyID', primary_key=True)  
    company = models.CharField(db_column='Company', max_length=200)  
    ...  
      
    class Meta:  
        db_table = 'tbl_Company'  
  
class TblCorporation(models.Model):
    contractcorporationid = models.AutoField(db_column='ContractCorporationID', primary_key=True)  
    contractid = models.ForeignKey(TblContract, 
            related_name="contract_corporation", 
            on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='ContractID')
    companyid = models.ForeignKey(TblCompany, 
            related_name="Company_Corporation", 
            on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='CompanyID') 
    e_percent = models.FloatField(db_column='E_Percent')   
    p_percent = models.FloatField(db_column='P_Percent')   
    c_percent = models.FloatField(db_column='C_Percent')  
  
    class Meta:  
        db_table = 'tbl_Corporation'
```

meanwhile using companyid__company in filtering like following one have no problem: `tblCorporation.objects.all().values('companyid__company')`